# UISearchBar keyboard not hiding iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have been attempting to hide a `UISearchBar` keyboard but my code fails to run successfully. I have the following code which **removes the cursor** but the keyboard continues to show:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; // using method search bar
     [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder]; // using actual object name
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

I have set the delegate in the .h as `<UISearchBarDelegate>` and set `searchBar.delegate = self;` in .m

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following methods for search an resign first responder:

```
- (UIView *)findFirstResponderBeneathView:(UIView *)view {
    for ( UIView *childView in view.subviews ) {
        if ( [childView respondsToSelector:@selector(isFirstResponder)] && [childView isFirstResponder] ) return childView;
        UIView *result = [self findFirstResponderBeneathView:childView];
        if ( result ) return result;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)hideKeyboard {
    [[self findFirstResponderBeneathView:self.view] resignFirstResponder];
}
```